# Importing java class from different sub directory

Tags: java, package

I have this directory in my java project

```
---Management( Directory)
---Home.java
----->models(subdirectory)
    ---Student.java
----->helper( subdirectory)
    ---Helpers.java
```

Home.java is using Helper.java file, so I import Helper like this in
    Home.java

```
import helper.Helper.*;
```

Helper.java is using Student.java. Can anyone tell me how to
    import Student.java file in Helper.java?

I've tried

```
import models.Student.*;
```

But I am getting error while doing this

Comment: Show your `package` definitions for each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it appears that the `Student` class is the `models` package.  If yes, it should be either:

```
import models.*;
```

or

```
import models.Student;
```

You should prefer the second one.  It's more readable.

If `management` is a package, then you should prepend that ahead of `models`.

Your project organization needs work.  You may not be using Maven yet, but I'd recommend their directory organization for projects for the day when you do.

```
/project
--/src
----/main
------/java      <-- Java packages and source go here
------/resources
----/test
------/java
------/resources
```